# Где получить список городов мира?

Tags: json, поиск-данных

Нужно единоразово скачать список городов мира (или хотя бы только России) в json формате. Кто-нибудь знает бесплатный ресурс?

Comment: А сложно преобразовать список в json? Взять можно... с той же википедии... Возможно в сети найти списки в других форматах. Вот я бы никогда не догадался выложить в сеть список в JSON. CSV, excel html но не json.

Comment: Geoip  например [maxmind](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот, если кому-нибудь понадобится вдруг
[Список городов в json формате](https://github.com/aZolo77/citiesBase/blob/master/cities.json)

Answer (score 1):

Через соц. сеть вк. Они там поиск по json осуществляют. Их исходные коды посмотри. Также статья есть: https://vk.com/dev/database.getCities
Материала на эту тему много как из вк забирать данные, поищи.

Answer (score 1):

У меня есть [список городов России](https://github.com/stepanovmax/towns-russia)(если вдруг кому-то не хватает городов этой страны) в JSON формате разбитый по регионам и со своими районами внутри каждого города.

Я долго пытался найти список городов России в JSON с регионами и с районами, но нигде такого не нашёл. Были варианты КЛАДР, ФИАС, ВК, просто чьи-то дампы, но нигде именно такого я не нашёл. И я задумал сделать полный и общедоступный список регионов, городов и районов городов РФ в JSON.

Любым предложениям по добавлению информации в этот список я буду только рад. Сейчас там отсутствуют районы городов. Но скоро и они заполнятся.

Также планирую туда внести данные по малым населённым пунктам типа деревень, посёлков и т.п.